# Parallel Transport along a surface

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I'm currently learning differential geometry for General Relativity. That being said, I would like to know how would you compute the parallel transport of a vector along a surface.

$\nabla_{\vec{u}}F =0$

Using a symmetric metric.

$$g_{\mu\nu} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
g_{11} & 0 & 0\\
0 & g_{22} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & g_{33}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\vec{u} \cdot\nabla F = u_1 \frac{\partial F}{ \partial x^1} g_{11} + u_2 \frac{\partial F}{ \partial x^2} g_{22} +  u_3 \frac{\partial F}{ \partial x^3} g_{33} = 0$$

This leaves me with one equation with three parameters.
What are the other conditions I would have to impose to get the values of $u$?

Comment: Your equation with $u^ig_{ii}\partial_{i}F$ is a red flag. Although possible you almost never see expressions with a dummy variable occuring more than twice. The correct expressions for the inner product between two vectors are $u\cdot v=u^ig_{ij}v^j$, for two covectors $\alpha\cdot\beta=\alpha_ig^{ij}\beta_ j$ and for a vector and covector pair $\alpha\cdot u=\alpha(u)=\alpha_iu^i$. Vectors are also commonly called contravariant vectors and covectors are examples of one-forms. Your example uses one vector (upper index) and one covector (gradient) so you don't need the $g_{ii}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** the way the parallel transport equation is written. You're rewriting the geometric definition incorrectly, as divergence of a scalar field, but what you should have is 3 equations for the components of the parallely-transported vector field.

First of all, we would say that something is parallely transported along a curve or a vector field, not a surface. This is because the parallel transport  is defined as happening along a **path**, not a **surface**. Of course, your surface can contain many paths, and parallel transport could happen along any of these.

Here's how you'd rewrite the equation, supposing that $\mathbf{F}$ is also a vector field:

$$ \nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{F} = 0 \\[0.5em]
u^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}F^{\beta} = 0\\[0.5em]
u^{\alpha}\big{[}\partial_{\alpha}F^{\beta} + \Gamma_{\alpha\mu}^{\beta}F^{\mu} \big{]} = 0
$$

The transition from the first to the second line is done by just expressing the covariant derivative of vector field $\mathbf{F}$ in components and making use of the fact that $\nabla$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear in the first (*bottom*) argument. Then, we're using the definition of the covariant derivative.

To obtain the Christoffel symbols, we use:

$$  \Gamma_{\alpha\mu}^{\beta} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\beta\nu}(g_{\alpha\nu,\mu} + g_{\mu\nu,\alpha} - g_{\alpha\mu,\nu} )$$.

Plugging this into the third equality would yield an equation that has to be satisfied in order for the vector field $\mathbf{F}$ to be parallel to $\mathbf{u}$. However, if we want to rephrase the task in the language of parallel transport of a vector ($\mathbf{F}(t=0)$)  and looking for its evolution, we re-express the third equality by assuming that $\mathbf{u}$ is affinely parametrized by a parameter $t$. From the very definition of the vector field as a differential operator, it holds that the action of $\mathbf{u}$ on any function can be written as:

$$ \mathbf{u}(f) = \frac{d}{dt}(f \circ \gamma)(t) = \frac{d}{dt}(f \circ x^{-1} \circ x \circ \gamma )(t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}}(f\circ x^{-1}) \frac{d}{dt}(x^{\alpha} \circ \gamma)(t) \equiv \partial_{\alpha}f \dot{\gamma}^{\alpha} \equiv u^{\alpha} \partial_{\alpha}f$$

In the above, the vector field $\mathbf{u}$ could be defined on the whole manifold, but we're concentrating on **one** of its integral curves.

In the second and third equality I wanted to show how a coordinate expression is derived, using the Leibniz rule on a composition of $f\circ x^{-1}$ and $x \circ \gamma $. We inserted $x^{-1} \circ x = id$, where $x: \mathcal{M} \rightarrow R^{n}$ is the coordinate map.

We can therefore treat the expression $u^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}F^{\beta}$ as a derivative of the composition $F^{\beta} \circ \gamma$ with respect to parameter $t$. Mind you, of course, that one needs to solve for an integral curve $\gamma$ of the $\mathbf{u}$ that one wishes to perform the parallel transport along. This requires solving the equation $\mathbf{u}(\gamma(t)) = \frac{d\gamma}{dt}$, or in coordinates: $u^{\alpha}(\gamma(t)) = \frac{d\gamma^{\alpha}}{dt}$.

For example, if $\mathbf{u} = x\partial_{y} - y\partial_{x}$, we'd be solving for $\gamma(t)=(\gamma^{x}(t), \gamma^{y}(t))$ such that:

$$ \frac{d\gamma}{dt} = \frac{d\gamma^{x}}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{d\gamma^{y}}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} $$
which gives:
$$ \frac{d\gamma^{x}}{dt} = - \gamma^{y}(t) \\  
\frac{d\gamma^{y}}{dt} =  \gamma^{x}(t)$$

Taking into account all of the above, the parallel transport equation is expressed as system of ODEs:

$$ \frac{dF^{\beta}(t)}{dt} = -\dot{\gamma}^{\alpha}(t)\Gamma^{\beta}_{\alpha\mu}(t)F^{\mu}(t), \\ 
F^{\beta}(0) = F^{\beta}_{0}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Parallel transport on a semi-Riemannian manifold $M$ equipped with it's Levi-Civita covariant derivative $\nabla$ requires two pieces of data:

- a tangent vector $v_p$ to be transported
- a curve $c: I \rightarrow M$ from $p$ (so that $c(0)=p$) along which it is to be transported

Then the parallel transport of $v_p$ along $c$ is a tangent field $V: I \rightarrow TM$ along $c$ such that

- $V(0) = v_p$

and

- $\nabla_\dot{c} V = 0$

In words, it say's that the tangent vector $v_p$ is being transported in a parallel manner along a curve when it's constant in the direction of the velocity of its carrying point on the curve.

Given all this, how you're thinking about parallel transport is a little confused. You need to specify a curve $c$ whose derivative $\dot{c}$ is your $\overrightarrow{u}$.

By the way, in the above I expressed parallel transport in terms of the covariant derivative. But they are in fact equivalent concepts, at least in this context. This means its possible to start off with an axiomatic definition of parallel transport and express the covariant derivative in terms of it.